# how can i fix my display post in my index.php

Tags: posts, css

hello i try to display my post into a div grid of 3 columns with the code

```
<div class="Jobs">
 <?php
  if(have_posts()) {
   while (have_posts()) {
    echo'<div class="info_Job">';
    echo '<h2>',the_title(),'</h2>';
    echo the_post_thumbnail(),'</div>';
      the_post();
      }
    }
 ?>
</div>
```

but instead to correctly display the 3 differents post y  2 of the same post and another like below[image]

how can i correct this please

Comment: Suggest posting the CSS for the classes in your code. The CSS will be important in how the content is displayed inside the divs. And, you might consider using a CSS Grid container, so that the display will be responsive. CSS Grid is quite clever in how it will display items, but will require a bit of research and testing. (I'm just learning it myself, so have no specific answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using commas as concatenators

you're echoing `the_title()` and `the_post_thumbnail()` (use get if you're
    echoing)

your `the_post()` was at the bottom

```
<div class="Jobs">
<?php
  if(have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
      the_post();
      echo'<div class="info_Job">';
      echo '<h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2>';
      echo get_the_post_thumbnail().'</div>'; 
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

If you don't want to use get but directly output do this instead:

```
<div class="Jobs">
<?php
  if(have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
      the_post();?>
      <div class="info_Job">
        <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
      </div>
<?php }
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: if for example i wanted this loop to display only specifique category of post of how could i do that ?

Comment: There are a couple ways.  it mostly depends on how you're going to use it.  Can you post it as another question and put the question link here as a comment.  I'll go through a couple options.

Comment: thanks a lot here the link : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319125/how-can-ispecify-category-post-on-my-home-page